# Dynamic CSS in Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, handlebars.js

Sorry if this is a bit of a noob Q. I'm a beginner to html/js/css.

I'm trying to create a HandleBars template of a crowdfunding thermometer. My problem is that I need the dynamic value to determine the width of the progress bar inside the Handlebars template, which requires CSS. I'm confused about the concept of dynamic CSS or whether it's possible.

Effectively, the progress on the thermometer is based on an aggregated value called {{cells.percComplete}} from Google Sheets, which is plugged into HandleBars.

I need the width of the template's 'progress' div to be equal to percComplete.

**Javascript**

```
var RBITemplate = Handlebars.compile($('#team-rbi-template').html());

 $('#total').sheetrock({
   url: mySpreadsheet,
   query: "select sum(B)/100 where (A = 'Donate $2 to Test Campaign')",
   labels: ['percComplete'],
  rowTemplate: RBITemplate
});
```

**Handlebars HTML template - here's where I'm stuck**

```
<ol id="total">
<script id="team-rbi-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div id="glass">
    <div id="progress" style="width: {{cells.percComplete }}"> (???)
    </div>
  </div>
....
```

But that can't be right.

Is it posible to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: what's the current output now?

Answer (score -1):

You can set style of div by javascript after template render